# AJAX refresh whole PHP page

Tags: php, ajax, refresh

How to update all php data on my page? I have communication system and I need to refresh all php data to update chat messages, users statuses and more for example every 750 miliseconds. I think AJAX do it but I don't know how.

Comment: you should not make the whole page refreshed either you can refresh the single div element using ajax  , since your using communication system you should only refresh oly the particular div which will look fine

Comment: It's enough only to reload for example div with id _messages_. I just need example and I can use codes from example.

Comment: If you are updating that fast you should probably be looking at websockets and not HTTP.

Comment: yeah websockets and socket io is even faster for real time applications like chat

Comment: And what if I whole page put into div and AJAX will refresh those div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this , it refreshes for every 750 secs generating random numbers for every 750 milli seconds

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(
 function() {
 setInterval(function() {
 var someval = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  $('#sample').text('Test' + someval);
 }, 700);  //Delay here = 750 milliseconds 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="sample">Testing refresh every 750 milliseconds</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please send me updated code with interval in miliseconds?

Comment: I think setInterval have to be in refreshdiv function

Comment: Thanks, i will try it

Comment: if it works mark this as right answer and up vote it as per

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182529/discussion-between-godwin-and-webcoder).